# Расположение элементов в зависимости от экрана

Tags: android-sdk, android

Привет.

Динамически создаю в LinearLayout (orientation="horizontal") кнопки, количество которых зависит от входного числа.

Вопрос в том, какой Layout (или надстройку) лучше выбрать, чтобы если входное число было слишком большим (т.е последняя кнопка уперлась в конец экрана), последующие кнопки создавались на новой строчке и т.д.

Comment: эм, я думаю это ручками надо отлавливать :)

Comment: @Макс Ровкин, этого то я и боюсь :)

Comment: @Sever, что поделать, не всегда же пользоваться готовым :)

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы просто взять и не использовать [ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)?

Comment: Спасибо, вам за совет. Но если бы было возможно, я бы его использовал. В условиях задачи поставленной передо мной, к сожалению, необходимо конкретно то, что я описал. Не спрашивайте зачем не спрашивайте почему, не в моих силах что-то изменить :)